# How do I fix the error in my permission system? (DISCORD.JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Error:

```
(node:6468) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of null
    at Object.module.exports.run (C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\Anuncios\comandos\vote.js:5:24)
    at C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\Anuncios\bot.js:141:57
    at C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\Anuncios\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4845:16
    at C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\Anuncios\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4283:12
    at C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\Anuncios\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2776:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
(node:6468) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
```

Code:

```js
const discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) =>{
    message.delete()
    if(!message.member.roles.some(r=> ["❪⚡❱❱❱Founder★★★★"].includes(r.name)) ) {
        return message.reply(` você não tem permissão de fazer isso!`)
    }
    let mensagem = args.join(' ')
    if(!args[0]) {
        return message.reply(`<:prohibited:814861316715839488> você não adicionou algo para ser avisado!`)
    }
    var embed = new discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    .setAuthor('SERVER - VOTAÇÃO', bot.user.avatarURL)
    .setDescription(mensagem)
    .setFooter(message.author.username, message.author.avatarURL)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setThumbnail(bot.user.avatarURL)
    bot.guilds.get('771513497069682711').channels.get(`786364363133026336`).send('@everyone').then(m =>{
    m.delete(100)
    })
    bot.guilds.get(`771513497069682711`).channels.get(`786364363133026336`).send(embed)
}

module.exports.config = {
    name: 'vote',
    aliases: ['votar', 'qcv']
}
```

I also tried to switch to a permission verification method, however, it generates another error and I always used this method for permission verification and do not know why it is giving this error, can anyone help me?

Comment: `message.member` is null. That could be for a whole host of reasons. I'm not familiar with the discord API but I wonder if calling `message.delete` immediately before trying to read it is causing an issue...

Comment: Indeed, try commenting it out. Or add some debugs, `console.log(message)`, before and after that delete()

Comment: For the record, your question is good, but could you update your question title so others can see what the problem is?

Comment: Calling `Message#delete` would delete the message on Discord, however within the current instance the `message` object would still be accessible. `message.member` may be returning null because the message may either be an invalid message object or the message was sent in a DM

Comment: How are you executing these commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of discord.js v12, you would refer to [`message.member.roles.cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=cache) instead.

```js
await message.delete();

if (!message.member.roles.cache.some(r => ['❪⚡❱❱❱Founder★★★★'].includes(r.name))) {
  return message.reply(` você não tem permissão de fazer isso!`);
}
```

As this isn't a [minified or reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), there's not much of a way to fully test this.

Do you have an example of what incurs these commands?

What confuses me is that you later try to reply to this message. Prior, it seems that you created a race condition by not deleting synchronously, but I might suggest conditionally delete the message once its context is no longer relevant or not delete at all.

Also, note that when you are deleting messages, you pass a timeout to an object, not an integer:

```js
await message.delete({ timeout })
```

Comment: This wouldn't explain why `message.member` is returning null. Adding cache would just cause an error of `cannot read cache of null`. Also I don't think calling `Message#delete` deletes the context message object

Comment: I just read your comments. I'm not sure how I'd test this as I don't see anything else immediately wrong.

Comment: That was a voting command... He created a message in EMBED in beautiful format and I manually put the reactions yes or no. I was using a really very old version of discord.js, now Updated and thanks to your help the error has been fixed. Thank you!